# Error in function arrow Unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I don't understand why my console show error in function *Arrow*

**Log Errors**

```
/home/david/js/script.js:3
var file = fs.readFile('file.txt', (err, data) => {
                                                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

**My function**

```
var fs = require("fs");

var file = fs.readFile('file.txt', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
});
```

Solution [reinstall node](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts/754836?stw=2#754836) :

Comment: What version of node do you have? run `node -v`. It properly doesn't support fat arrow functions.

Comment: My version the node is v0.10.25

Comment: @DavidHackro Arrow functions are only supported automatically [in Node v4 and newer](http://node.green/#arrow-functions). v0.12 permits them when using `--harmony` flags.

Comment: thanks! @JonathanLonowski

Comment: @JonathanLonowski AFAIK `--harmony` will not enable fat arrow functions in 0.10.

Comment: Use babel for compile code or latest version node.